# Need Authorization Header in test DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to test some views by the url but seems I'm blocked with the credentials, I see other post with the same problem and try to follow them but I'm still as the sane point

test_web_share_file_folder_view_set.py

```
class WebShareFileFolderViewSetTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='my_user', password='my_password')
        headers = web_backend_api_access_headers()
        self.token = headers['Authorization']
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_list_with_search(self):
        WebShareFileFactoryBoy(name="file_with_search", path="path_with_search")

        url = reverse('web-share-file-folders-list')
        request = self.factory.get(url, {'search': 'file_with_search'})
        request.user = self.user

        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer' + self.token)
        response = self.client.get(url,  headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token})
        print(response.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertTrue('file_with_search' in response.data['results'][0]['name'])
```

here the error when I start the test

```
FAIL: test_list_with_search (tests.test_web_share_file_folder_view_set.WebShareFileFolderViewSetTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-\tests\test_web_share_file_folder_view_set.py", line 32, in test_list_with_search
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
AssertionError: 401 != 200
```

and here the print of response.data

```
{'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Need Authorization Header', code='authentication_failed')}
```

If anyone has an idea :?
thank you

SOLUTION: force_authenticate was the solution

```
def test_of_BranchViewSet_with_delete_request(self):
    self.user = baker.make(User)
    url = reverse('branch-list')
    self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
    response = self.client.delete(url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

I try to access to the view to make a test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credentials method can be used to set headers that will then be included on all subsequent requests by the test client.

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

# Include an appropriate Authorization: header on all requests.
token = Token.objects.get(user__username='lauren')
client = APIClient()
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
```

2nd:

```
# Here user is my requested user and i'm forcefully authenticate user to make successfully requset.
self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
```

Complete test case here:

```
def test_of_BranchViewSet_with_delete_request(self):
    self.user = baker.make(User)
    url = reverse('branch-list')
    self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
    response = self.client.delete(url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#headers-authentication

Comment: In my case I use Bearer as token :/
headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token})
(I try your solution tomorrow)

Comment: I just updated my answer please have a look

Comment: I just tried, but I can't use Token, I don't use it in this app :/

AttributeError: type object 'Token' has no attribute 'objects'

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6250#issuecomment-430410363

Comment: which one you tried?

Comment: ah! the second options work well! I edit the post with your solution ;)

Comment: Good to hear that...!